# webpack internal contains lib's node_modules

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I have a project that contains 2 libs: common-libs, common-services, which are built by webpack, then in my main project, I make them as dependencies thru file, like "common-libs": "../common-libs",  when I start the main project, the chrome dev tool has a "webpack-internal://" tab, which shows the 2 libs structure, my question is how to make the node_modules folder not showing up?

I tried to manually remove the node_modules folder from common-libs folder, then the structure looks like below which is perfect and the common-services stay the same, but I need to keep developping so I can't npm install then remove node_modules over and over again.

[image]